# What is JObjC.jar used for?

Tags: objective-c, macos, jar, java

I'm trying to bundle JRE with my own application's installer. For this purpose I'm trying to cut down OpenJDK to remove all rarely used features. In a recent OpenJDK 7u40 for Mac OS X I see a JAR called JObjC.jar and a complementary native lib libJObjC.dylib. What are they used for and can I safely cut them down without breaking anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove this, a lot of things could potentially break.

Given that you're prepared to do bleeding-edge things like this, I suggest you instead use OpenJDK 8 with the new Compact Profiles features - using them is probably a lot safer than trying to manually reduce the size of the footprint.

Comment: Yep, I was considering this too, but my code has to be reusable on Android, and that requires JDK 6 compatibility. With 8.0 it is quite difficult to achieve.